# Error:(16, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments on root project 'delta-bartalk' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to view a layout in a project. The layout shows no images. Everytime I open the project I get an error right now the error being shown is

> Error:(16, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments 
>   [build_6r57r9htisolgl7blgqlf257v$_run_closure2@22204001] on root project 'delta-bartalk' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
>
> Open file (link to // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.)

I am a beginner with Android studio so I have no idea what to do.

Thanks

_-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Theses are the files - first Top-level build file Name: delta-bartalk

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application' //[change recommended by comment from Eugen Martynov]


buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

android {
}
dependencies {
}
```

---

This next code is called bartalk\build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Comment: I tried to add this line to the top of the Top - level build file. I get a new error Error:Cause: buildToolsVersion is not specified.

Comment: Post you build.gradle files

Comment: I added both build.gradle files to my post above

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti, , please take a look if you don't mind

Comment: @Eugen Martynov plesae take a look if you dont mind

Comment: OK remove added line that I suggested from parent `build.gradle` file also remove `android` section in parent `build.grade`

Comment: Thank you @Eugen Martynov. It works now. Do you mind explaining what was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your top level file you have to remove

```
android { } dependencies { }
```

And

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```